# Передача данных между компонентами React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть две компоненты одного уровня, мне нужно передать значение которое было получено в компоненте `NavigationBar` в компоненту `SearchLine`

```
import React from 'react';

import NavigationBar from '../NavigationBar/NavigationBar';
import MainComponent from '../MainComponent/MainComponent';

class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return(
        <>
            <NavigationBar />
            <MainComponent />
        </>
    );
  }
}
export default BaseComponent;
```

компонента `SearchLine` содержится в `MainComponent`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router';

import SearchLine from '../MainComponent/SearchLine/SearchLine';

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <>
            <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/all_songs/" component={SearchLine} />
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Redirect to="/all_songs/" />
                    </Route>
             </Switch> 
        </>
    );
  }
}
export default MainComponent;
```

вот компонента `NavigationBar`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './NavigationBar.css';

class NavigationBar extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {artName: ''};
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({artName: e.target.value});
  }

render() {
    const artistName = this.state.artistName;
    return(
        <div className="navBlock">
            <img src={require('./search-solid.svg')} width={17} height={17} className="navImage"/>
            <input 
                placeholder="Type in to Search..." 
                className="input-title" 

                value={artistName}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />

            <div className="navContainer">
                <ul>
                    <Link to="/all_songs">All Songs</Link>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
                <ul>
                    <Link to="/albums">Albums</Link>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Я не понимаю как мне правильно взять из `NavigationBar` значение, которое было введено в `input`, и передать его в `SearchLine`?

Answer (score 1):

Без `Redux` можно пойти путем передачи значения через `props`. Добавить в стейт базового компонента переменную, куда будем сохранять значение, а также добавить метод, который будет записывать это значение. Передадим значение через пропсу в `MainComponent`, а метод записи значения передадим через пропсу в `NavigationBar`. Получим что-то вроде следующего кода:

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { artName: '' }; // переменная, в которой будем хранить значение

    this.onChangeArtValue = this.onChangeArtValue.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeArtValue(value) {
    this.setState({ artName: value });
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <>
            <NavigationBar onChangeArtValue={this.onChangeArtValue} />
            <MainComponent artName={this.state.artName} />
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Далее перейдем в компонента `NavigationBar` и испольуем переданный через `props` метод внутри ранее написанного `handleChange` метода:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.props.onChangeArtValue(e.target.value); // вызвали метод переданный через пропсу
}
```

Теперь при изменении значения внутри инпута в `NavigationBar` компоненте, будет меняться значение в стейте `BaseComponent` компонента. Оно же при изменении будет пробрасываться в `MainComponent` компонент и вызывать ререндеринг. Осталось внести правки в сам `MainComponent` компонент. Нам нужно написать вспомогательный метод для `Route`, чтобы правильно передать пропсу в компонент:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderSearchLine = this.renderSearchLine.bind(this);
  }

  renderSearchLine() {
    // возвращаем SearchLine с переданной пропсой 
    return (
      <SearchLine artName={this.props.artName} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/all_songs/" component={this.renderSearchLine} />
          <Route path="/">
            <Redirect to="/all_songs/" />
          </Route>
        </Switch> 
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Можно не выделять отдельный метод, но я сделал для наглядного понимания отдельный метод. После этого, внутри компонента `SearchLine` появится пропса `artName`, для этого будет достаточно обратиться в пропсы, для получения ее значения: `this.props.artName`. То есть, логика передачи через пропсы достаточно прямолинейна и ясна.

Если данный подход покажется слишком громоздким, то советую обратить внимание на одну очень полезную штуковину под названием [**Redux**](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

Тебе необходимо использовать подъем состояния (обратный поток данных).

Вот структура компонента BaseComponent:

```js
import React from 'react';

import NavigationBar from '../NavigationBar/NavigationBar';
import MainComponent from '../MainComponent/MainComponent';

class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        yourStateName: null,
    };
    lifting = (value) =>
        this.setState({yourStateName: value});
    render() {
        return(
            <>
                <NavigationBar lifting={this.lifting.bind(this)} />
                <MainComponent yourAttributeName={this.state.yourStateName} />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default BaseComponent;
```

Здесь мы добавили состояние через упрощенный синтаксис yourNameState: null, создали функцию lifting, поднимающую состояние дочернего компонента NavigationBar, которую мы отправили ему же как свойство lifting, а также, добавили в MainComponent свойство yourAttributeName, в котором и будет содержаться необходимое ему состояние из NavigationBar, которое теперь уже будет храниться в BaseComponent в качестве state yourStateName.

А вот уже в компоненте NavigationBar нужно правильно применить функцию lifting в функцию-обработчик события onChange элемента input.

Вот структура компонента NavigationBar:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './NavigationBar.css';

class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {artName: ''};
    }
    lifting = this.props.lifting; //Michael Pecker: добавляем классу метод lifting, значение берем из this.props
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({artName: e.target.value});
        this.lifting(e.target.value); //Michael Pecker: используем функцию lifting, чтобы отправить состояние родителю
    }
    
    render() {
        const artistName = this.state.artistName;
        return(
            <div className="navBlock">
                <img src={require('./search-solid.svg')} width={17} height={17} className="navImage"/>
                <input
                    placeholder="Type in to Search..."
                    className="input-title"

                    value={artistName}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                <div className="navContainer">
                    <ul>
                        <Link to="/all_songs">All Songs</Link>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <ul>
                        <Link to="/albums">Albums</Link>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```